# Derived class remains abstract

Tags: c++

Why is the class `TB` abstract in the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct IA
{
    virtual long X() = 0;
};
struct IB: public IA
{
    virtual long Y() = 0;
};

struct TA: public IA
{
    virtual long X() { return 5; };
};

struct TB: public IB, public TA
{
   // virtual long X() { return TA:: X(); };
    virtual long Y() { return 7; };
};

int main()
{
    TB b;
}


main.cpp:25: error: cannot declare variable 'b' to be of abstract type 'TB'
     TB b;
```

Comment: Do you realize that `TB` class inherits from `IA` twice?

Comment: Is this famous Diamond Problem?

Comment: I don't know? @ManthanTilva

Comment: This issue is explained at  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-diamond

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `TB` is inheriting **twice** from `IA` because `IA` is parent of both `IB` and `TA`. To fix it you need to either redesign your class hierarchy or use [`virtual inheritance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Virtual_base_classes):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct IA
{
    virtual long X() = 0;
};
struct IB: public virtual IA // virtual inheritance here
{
    virtual long Y() = 0;
};

struct TA: public virtual IA // and here
{
    virtual long X() { return 5; };
};

struct TB: public IB, public TA
{
   // virtual long X() { return TA:: X(); };
    virtual long Y() { return 7; };
};

int main()
{
    TB b;
}
```